# Variable in an AutoIt script only recognizes the first character from an input box

Tags: variables, autoit, inputbox

I am trying to create script that is able to recognize a multi-character variable (a number in xx.xx format) after entering into input box. After entering the variable in xx.xx format into the input box, the variable will only show up as a single character, using the first character. For example, if I put 10.80 into the input box, the variable when reused when the script is run, will only show up as 1.

Here are parts of the script that uses the variable:

```
Dim $price
$price = InputBox("Offer Price", "Input Offer Price")

Send("{TAB}")

Send("{"& $price &"}") ; Enters variable

Send("{DOWN}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Send("{100000000000000000}")
```

sends the character 1.

```
Send("100000000000000000")
```

sends the characters 100000000000000000.

A lot of people get confused with when to use {curly braces} with Send.

Change your script to do this instead:

```
Send($price) ; enters variable
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the feeling I may be entirely misunderstanding your question but you seem to be asking for an input box that checks if the input meets a particular input pattern then gives you the left most character of it.  This will do that.

```
While 1
    Local $responce = InputBox('Offer Price', 'Input offer price in XX.XX format.')
    If @error == 1 Then
        MsgBox(0, 'Cancel Pressed', 'You pressed cancel exiting loop.')
        ExitLoop
    EndIf

    If StringRegExp($responce, '\d{2}\.\d{2}') Then
        MsgBox(0, 'Success', 'The input fit the pattern XX.XX and the left most character of it = ' & StringLeft($responce, 1))
        ExitLoop
    Else
        MsgBox(0, 'Invalid Input', 'The input needs to be a number in XX.XX format.')
    EndIf
WEnd
```